# Forticlient VPN can't be installed on 23.10

Tags: dependencies, vpn, 23.10

To install the application, i follow the documentation available at this [doc link](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/forticlient/7.2.2/linux-release-notes/213138).

During the installation i found some errors:

1. Wrong gpg key. [solution](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Support-Forum/Forticlient-7-2-2-install-on-Linux-Mint-21-2-Cinnamon-and-Ubuntu/td-p/283518)
2. Not installable **libgconf-2-4**. [solution](https://2h3ph3rd.medium.com/how-to-install-libgconf-2-4-on-ubuntu-23-10-fec6bda8d5f5)
3. Not installable **libappindicator1**.

The question is, how to solve this third error?

Comment: Same boat. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Install ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of third problem is mark all checkbox on ubuntu apps:

[image: mark all box on ubuntu apps]